# When to expect driver support for Qualcom Atheros (rev 20) wifi cards?

Tags: wireless, drivers, ubuntu-drivers

I recently purchased a Lenovo G-50-80 FUIN laptop. It hosts Qualcom Atheros(rev 20) wifi card. I could not find the drivers for this card anywhere. Can we expect next distribution of ubuntu(oct 15 release) to include those?

Here is the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` command:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0041]
(rev 20)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3545]
```

PS: Web search done before posting here lead me to something clled ath10k drivers and that these drivers are available in linux kernel version 3.20.0. As far as I know, no ubuntu distribution has kernel 3.20.x.
I have tried ubuntu 12.04, 14.04 (both 32 and 64 bit) and 15.04(64 bit) but no success yet. Also tried one version of mint OS but the wifi doesn't work in any of those systems.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

This device is not supported yet. There is a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1436940).

Device `[168c:0040]` `QCA99X0_2_0` is already supported in linux-next.

There is a good chance that same driver supports `0041` device too. But it will need a kernel patch to include the device ID.

I can build a module for testing and post it to the bug report. If you spend some effort on testing, the solution may come faster.

There is no kernel 3.20. Linus Torvalds decided to rename it to 4.0.

But still your device is not supported by any kernel yet.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Yeah I can help you in testing your module.

Comment: Then look into that but report. I will try to fix it as soon as find some time.